# PHP & SQL post data from returning URL string to database

Tags: php, mysql, http-post

I have a shopping cart system that sends data to a gateway, and returns using a PHP string.  I am trying to work out how to POST that data to my database, a new table would be preferred.

Currently the information doesn't save to the database and I need it now to do so.

Current string:

```
$this->form_action_url = 'https://www.paymate.com/PayMate/ExpressPayment?mid=[name]&return=http://[website]/index.php?main_page=checkout_process';
```

New string to get the data:

```
$this->form_action_url = 'https://www.paymate.com/PayMate/ExpressPayment?mid=username&transactionID&ref&responseCode&buyerEmail&billingSurname&return=http://[website]/index.php?main_page=checkout_process';
```

I have access to the database which means I can setup a table Paymate, with headers appropriate to the data.

The string will work, but I don't know how to get the `transactionID` `ref` `responseCode` to record to the database.

Is there a step-by-step guide, or do I need to get a whole new module written for this?

Can someone with no PHP experience do this, or do I need a coder to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these URLs intended to be form actions (i.e. your customer is taken over to that site before being redirected back to you) or an API call (your app does it transparently in the background)?

Comment: @halfer these are indeed form actions.  Our customer is taken to the site with pre-updated fields, confirms the order to be processed then upon completion the provider returns them to our store.  (I wish I had an API and there is a provision for it, but I wouldn't know where to start and coders are very expensive :(()

Comment: Right, so the user is taken to the payment site, returned to you, and it then return success/fail payment details in the query string. You want to record those details. Is that the problem?

Comment: @halfer Yes, that is correct :)  I get the string that I've included above, but I don't know how to get that in to my SQL table.  :(

Comment: If your returned data is in URL form, use `parse_url()` to split it into constituent parts, then connect to a database via PDO or MySQLi, then prepare a parameterised `INSERT` query, and execute, supplying the values for your parameters. See php.net/pdo for an example.